# How to make vim automatically write the fixed comment at beginning?

Tags: python, vim

Everytime I create a new python file by Vim, I need to type #!/usr/bin/env python. So I intended to let Vim do it for me. However, I just know a little about vimscript and I just try a little bit which I don't think it will work and right, it does not work.

```
:autocmd FileType python i#!/usr/bin/env python<esc>
```

Can anybody help me to implement this use case?

Answer (score 2):

- `FileType` is not the right event; use `BufNewFile` instead.
- You are using a normal mode command, `i#!/usr/bin/env python<esc>` where you should use an ex command. Something like:

  ```
  0put='#!/usr/bin/env python'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  normal I#!/usr/bin/env python
  ```

Here is a working solution that also puts the cursor below your shebang:

```
augroup myTemplates
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile *.py silent 0put='#!/usr/bin/env python'|2
augroup END
```

NOTE: the Vim documentation has a short section devoted to that topic, see `:help template'.